# Increase in auto policy premium after removing 3rd car

Tags: united-states, insurance, car-insurance, new-jersey

My wife and I had 3 cars with Allstate.  Homeowners, policy, umbrella policy, everything with Allstate.  Same agent for 35+ years.  Now the "kid" runs the show, somewhat arrogant, and enjoys all the work daddy built up for him to reap.

Anyway, I recently sold a 2004 sports car leaving 2 cars (a 2016 VW and a 2017 Lexus) on the policy instead of 3 cars.

We are both over 65 (66 and 65).  We both use cars for pleasure.  No commute/work, less than 5,000 miles each car a year, always.  The full coverage amount for 3 cars was $1,500 each 6 months here in NJ (full collision, liability, fully covered 500/500/etc.)

The deleted sports car was $480 each 6 months, and after 2 months in force (to the day), they refunded $250 when cancelling the sports car.  However they increased to premium on the Lexus and lowered it on the VW, slightly.  The refund in real world numbers should be about $320, not $250.

If you compare line item by line item with each policy/vehicle side by side, the numbers do not make sense.

I know it's only a few dollars, but heck, I feel like I'm getting ripped off, and I need to fully comprehend the procedures allowed or are they getting over on me?

Comment: Did you ask the reason for the increase? And was there perhaps a discount in place for you having three cars with the same company?

Comment: What happened with me, when I had more vehicles than drivers on my policy, was that none was considered a "primary" vehicle. When you have equal drivers & vehicles, each vehicle becomes a "primary" for one of the drivers. Or, at least, that's how my provider at the time evaluated them.

Answer (score 4):

Car insurance premiums change continuously, and anytime you make a change to your policy the insurance company has an opportunity to adjust your rates.

Fortunately for you, there are lots of insurance agents and insurance companies. If you aren’t happy with your agent or your rate, it is time to shop around for a better deal. That will tell you if you are being overcharged or if your new rates are still in line with the rest of the insurance market.

Answer (score -2):

After trying four car insurance companies, they seem all to work the same way - they try to get you with very low rates, and then increase them every year by 15% or more. After some years, you get annoyed and when checking find again very low prices with most others.

So your choice is to change insurance every two years, or get milked more and more every year. There is no such thing as ‚being a long-term valued customer‘.